# What specs do I look at to get a screw-on teleconverter that works with my V1 and adapted lens?

Tags: teleconverter

My camera is a Nikon V1 (1"-format sensor). I have a native Nikon 1 30-110mm lens, with Olympus C210 screw-on teleconverter, which works without vignetting from 60mm length onwards. This works because the C210 is designed for a small sensor.

I'm expecting a Konica Hexanon 200mm f/3.5 prime telephoto. Being old, it's designed for 35mm SLR cameras. It has 67mm filter threads.

So I'm assuming, I need some kind of teleconverter that is made for full frame cameras, especially with 67mm thread, despite my sensor being 1". Am I correct?

If yes, what are the specs I'm looking for so that I can make sure to get one that works with the Hexanon and my camera?

Comment: Why do you want to use a teleconverter on the 200mm lens? What are you trying to achieve? Would you be better served obtaining a (zoom) lens with a focal length longer than 200mm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, you are not correct. The Olympus C210 was designed for 35mm film cameras** (granted, they were fixed-lens "bridge"-type cameras), so it was designed for full frame with a lens set to 110mm. The vignetting issues you have with it are probably because it simply wasn't designed to be matched with any focal lengths other than 110mm.

With screw-on teleconverters, all you're really doing is putting a magnifying glass in front of your lens. That lens isn't part of the lens's optical design, and therefore can cause image quality issues, as well as limit the ability of the lens to focus at one end of its range.

All you really need to worry about is the thread size. So getting one with a 67mm thread to fit your Hexanon is the only spec you need to worry about. However, the image quality of using one of these cheap TCs, especially the higher the magnification factor, may not be great, and isn't going to be at all the same as just using a longer native lens. You'll also be reducing your maximum aperture. And at 500-600mm equivalency, you should probably be looking into some form of stabilization, handholding that combination could get very difficult, especially with manual focus.

You may want to consider saving up to get a used Nikon 70-300 and the FT-1 adapter if you have a moving subject in mind, and can't cough up the $1k for the Nikon 1 70-300.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will definitely get the 70-300 in the future